# Copy Magento live site to local server for backup

Tags: php, mysql, magento, centos6

I have copied an entire Magento live installation to install to a local centos 6.7 server(virtual) in my local network.
Here are what I did:

- Zipped and copied _public_html folder from live site
- Took a backup from live mysql database
- Set up in mac with parallels a centos 6.7 installation with php5.5 and mysql5.5
- I set up Apache 2.2

Everything seems ok and working.

The next step I did was to install magento 1.9.1(same version with my live site) from scratch to centos. Everything ok. Magento home page worked.

Then I copied my live public_html folder to local public_html folder.
My local folder is in /var/www/html/site/ .
I changed the local.xml file with local credentials.
Then I restored the live database with:

```
mysql -u root -p magento < /home/username/magento_sample_data_for_1.14.0.0.sql
```

And for last in phpmyadmin I run:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';
```

and changed all the links.Also I deleted all cache folders and session.

My local centos has a static ip which is pointed to a dev domain inside my host file.
All these are done in a Mac pro with parallels.

The problem that when I hit the domain I get time out. Magento isn't loading.
Here are my php and sql settings:

```
Mysqld

innodb_thread_concurrency = 2 * [numberofCPUs] + 2
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
thread_concurrency = [number of CPUs] * 3
thread_cache_size = 32
table_cache = 1024
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_limit = 2M
join_buffer_size = 8M
tmp_table_size = 256M
key_buffer = 32M
innodb_autoextend_increment=512
max_allowed_packet = 16M
max_heap_table_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10G
myisam_max_extra_sort_file_size = 10G
myisam_repair_threads = 1
```

---

```
Php

realpath_cache_size = 32k
realpath_cache_ttl = 7200
max_execution_time = 90
max_input_time = 90
memory_limit = 256M
default_socket_timeout = 90
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
output_buffering = 4096
```

I am stucked. Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the server working and everything set up correctly? If instead of magento you place test file test.php and try to call mylocal.dev/test.php does it run?

Comment: Yes. Everything seems fine. I see info.php file, phpmyadmin and centos Apache test page. Only Magento.dev isn't working

Comment: hmm i see, are you getting any errors? 
Edit the Magento bootstrap index.php in your document root and uncomment the following line:  ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

Maybe you need to raise your max_execution_time & memory_limit in php. Also double check that you have set the base_urls correctly on core_config_data (add the urls without '/' in the end)

Comment: I uncommented the ini_set you told me but nothing happend. I found though that there was a file apc.php which was causing the problem. I renamed it and worked.I can see the frontpage just fine....The problem now is that when a press a link from the site I get the requested url not found. Why is this? What am I missing now?

Comment: Fixed with created .htaccess file which was not moved by mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have understood . You are using using old magento file from live site but data base is new . So here in your new DB doesn't have previous extensions tables which already in the live site. My suggestion. Please follow the below step hope this will helps you. 
1. Download new magento version which you want to install
2. Import live database to your local db
3. Try to to install new magento by pointing to the live. Means when you will go for installing magnto then it will prompt to put DB credentials.Then you need to put old DB details which is in your local sever. 
4. it can take few mints or if your live site much lower version then it can take more than an hour. 
5. When it will be done then you need to migrate only the files from local and community folder as well as frontend design and admin design file. Keep in mind we aleady have migrated DB. 
Hope this will helps you . 
thanks.

Comment: I didn't use old magento file. I installed local magento 1.9.1 from scratch which is the same version with my live site. I took a copy from live public_html and replace the local public_html folder. Then I took the live database and restore it to the local database.Changed the local.xml file and cleared cache. So this is a clone from live site...It should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: No it will not work.Hope my suggestion works for you. Thanks.